# Using arrays, I have to print 4 hands named East, west, north and south with 13 cards each specified by spades, clubs etc

Tags: java

This is my code but this does not even work
Steps to do the program:

1. Use Math.random() and the remainder operator to generate 52 distinct numbers from 0 to 51. These numbers will represent a deck of card and let’s call it deckOfCard. (Now you have a one-dimensional array of size 52.) For this step, you should write a method called generateCard which returns nothing but accepts one argument which is the array variable that represents the deck of card (pass
   array by reference).
2. To make sure your program works, you should print the number when the array has been generated before you continue to the next step. Write a method called
   printCard which returns nothing but accepts 3 arguments as following: (1) the
   array, (2) the number of output per line, and (3) the width for each output. You are going to call this method to print the contents of the array in the format of 13 numbers per line and 5 spaces per number.
3. Use a two dimensional array of 4x13 representing 4 hands of cards. Let’s call it hands. Write a method called deal which accepts two arguments, one is the
   deckOfCard and the other is hands. This method distributes the card to the four
   parties (assume that the order of distribution is East, North, West, and South.)
4. To make sure that your step 4 works, you should call printCard before you move on
   to the next step.
5. Assuming that Spade will take the values from 0 to 12, Heart from 13 to 25,
   Diamond from 26 to 38, and Club from 39 to 51. You are going to write a method
   called printHands which will print the hand of each party similar to the following.
                   NORTH
                 S : A Q J 10 9 2
                 H : J 8 2
                 D : K
                 C : A J 9
           Same for other directions
   To do this, one easy way is to set up a 3-dimensional array of              4x4x13 and let’s call it fourDecks. The first dimension represents a 
   deck of card and each of the first dimensions represents the cards owned by each player. Initially all values are all 0,
   indicating that none is owned by any player. The 2nd and the 3rd dimensions will
   represent a particular card. The value of a particular slot will be changed to ‘1’ from
   ‘0’ if that card is held by a certain party. Eventually, there will be total of 52 ‘1’s and
   each party (or each of the 1st dimensions) will contain 13 non-overlapping ’1’s.

   ```
     public class deckOfCards {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         int[] deckOfCard = new int[52];
         generateCard(deckOfCard);
         printCard(deckOfCard, 13, 5);
         deal(deckOfCard, 4);
         //printCard(null);
       }
      public static void generateCard( int[] args)
      {
       int[] deckOfCard = new int[52];
       String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
       String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",           

               10", "Jack", "Quenn", "King"};

       //Initialize the cards
       for (int i = 0; i < deckOfCard.length; i++)
           deckOfCard[i] = i;

       //Shuffle the Cards
       for (int i = 0; i < deckOfCard.length; i++)
       {
           //Generate an index randomly
           int index = (int)(Math.random() * deckOfCard.length);
           int temp = deckOfCard[i];
           deckOfCard[i] = deckOfCard[index];
           deckOfCard[index] = temp;

           //if (flag[index] == 0)
           //{

           String suit = suits[deckOfCard[i] / 13];
           String rank = ranks[deckOfCard[i] % 13];
       }
       String[] deck = new String[ranks.length * suits.length];
       int i, j = 0;
       for ( i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) 
           for ( j = 0; j < suits.length; j++) 
               deck[suits.length*i + j] = ranks[i] + " of " + suits[j]; 
       //int i = 0;
       //int j = 0;
       System.out.println(ranks[i] + " of " + suits[j]);
        }
       public static void printCard( int[] args, int number, int width)
       {
       int[] deckOfCard = new int[52];
       //generateCard(deckOfCard);
       final int NUMBER = 13;

       for (int i = 0; i < deckOfCard.length; i++)
       {
       if (deckOfCard[i] % NUMBER == 0){
           System.out.printf("%-5s\n", i);
       }
       System.out.println();
       }
       //generateCard(null);
       //System.out.println(" NORTH: ");
       //for (int i = 0; i < deckOfCard.length; i++) 
       //{

           /*System.out.println("Spades: " + rank );
           System.out.println("Hearts: " + rank );
           System.out.println("Diamonds: " + rank );
           System.out.println("Clubs: " + rank );*/
       }

       public static void deal( int[] args, int hands)
       {
       int[] deckOfCard = new int[52];
       final String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
       final String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",  "                                                                                             

                               9, "10", "Jack", "Quenn", "King"};
       int numberOfPlayers = 0;
       int[][] hands1 = new int[4][13];
       int [][] cardArray= new int[numberOfPlayers][26]; //Declares,   i   

                                 initialize 2D array
           for (int i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++){
               for (int j=0; j<cardArray[i].length; j++){
               cardArray[i][j]=i;
           }
             }
             //printCard(deckOfCard, 13, 5);

           int k=0;
           while (k < deckOfCard.length)
             {  //This should transfer the necessary cards based on # of pl        a                      player
               for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++)
               {
                   for (int j = 0; j < ((52/numberOfPlayers)+1); j++)
                   {
                       cardArray[i][j]=deckOfCard[k];
                       k += 1;
                   }

               }

           }

           System.out.print("East: ");
               for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) { //prints the first 13 cards f                    
                   String suit = suits[deckOfCard[i] / 13];
                       String rank = ranks[deckOfCard[i] % 13];
                                 System.out.print( rank + suit + " ");

              }
                 }
   //public static void printHands(int[] args, int )
                     }
   ```

Comment: Are you OK with how your question looks here? I mean formatting

Comment: This is too huge... Instead of dumping your whole problem & code, just ask about the specific issue you're getting if any...

Answer (score 1):

Alright it's a lot to take in and I don't have an infinite amount of time so I'm gonna answer the first two tasks for now and then hope it will help you with the rest.

It seems like you're at the beginning of learning programming, so I'm gonna really take it step by step here.

First things first: Do NOT name your class beginning with a lower case letter. Just call it DeckOfCards instead of deckOfCards. It's easier to see what's a class and what's a method that way.

Next: I don't really care if you use the standard java way of placing { or do it like I prefer, but decide on one and stick with it. Don't mix them.

What I mean is:

```
blabla {
}
```

and

```
blabla
{
}
```

Either is fine, but not both.

---

### Task 1: generateCard

Right off the bet, you initialize your array twice:

```
 int[] deckOfCard = new int[52];
```

You do that right before you call generateCard and it's the first thing you do in that method. Please only do that once. Also, your second array is completely unrelated to your first one. If I understand the task correctly, that's not what was intended here. 
I believe you were supposed to actually fill the array that you got as a parameter.
So instead of using that line in the beginning of your method, just remove it and change the parameter name from args to deckOfCard.

Then you initialize two additional arrays that you use for naming. I don't really understand why as it didn't say that in task #1, but I did see where you used it which I'll get to later.

The next part is actually fine except for

```
String suit = suits[deckOfCard[i] / 13];
String rank = ranks[deckOfCard[i] % 13];
```

Those two lines are completely pointless as you never use those two variables again.

Next you do something I don't understand. Were you supposed to create a string array? I think you just did it to test if it worked but task 2 does ask you to write a print method so why do it here, too?

Here's what it would look like if you listen to all I said:

```
public class DeckOfCards {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] deckOfCard = new int[52];
        generateCard(deckOfCard);
        printCard(deckOfCard, 13, 5);
    }

    public static void generateCard(int[] deckOfCard) {
        //Initialize the cards
        for (int i = 0; i < deckOfCard.length; i++)
            deckOfCard[i] = i;

        //Shuffle the Cards
        for (int i = 0; i < deckOfCard.length; i++) {
            //Generate an index randomly
            int index = (int)(Math.random() * deckOfCard.length);
            int temp = deckOfCard[i];
            deckOfCard[i] = deckOfCard[index];
            deckOfCard[index] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Task 2: printCard

Again, you are naming your parameter arg and just don't use it. That's pointless. Just call it was it is: deckOfCard.
And don't initialize it yet again.
It's also completely unnecessary to call generateCard from here.

There is also no need to define NUMBER. Use number instead (one of your parameters).

I'm not sure what the for loop is supposed to do here... If you only write something every time your card number can be divided by number that's completely pointless. The number will be 13. Which means you will only print the cards 0, 13, 26 and 39 (there is no 52 because your cards go from 0-51) and a lot of blank lines.

```
public static void printCard(int[] deckOfCard, int number, int width){
        for (int i = 0; i < deckOfCard.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(deckOfCard[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) System.out.print(" ");
            if ((i + 1) % number == 0) 
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

What I do here is print each and every card. The if will break into the next line after every 13 cards. It has to be i+1 because once you reach index 12, that will be your 13th card.

The second for is for the spaces between the cards. I know there are better ways but I felt like this one was easy to understand.

I assume everything after that was for later tasks, so I ignored it completely for this one.

---

Now... as far as I can see from these two tasks alone, you don't understand how parameters work and what "pass array by reference" (task 1) meant. It means the following:
If you pass an array in java as a parameter, you can use that array and actually change it's values and once you finished that method (in your main method), the changed values will still BE in the array.
That's called pass by reference, because you pass the actual array and changes of the array carry over.

In contrast to that, there's "pass by value" which you have with primitve data types. If you have a parameter like "int number", then if you write number = 3 and finish the method, the initial number will be unchanged.

Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[1];
    array[0] = 5;
    int number = 10;
    changeStuff(array, number);
    System.out.println("Array[0] = " + array[0]);
    System.out.println("number = " + number);
}

public static void changeStuff(int[] array, int number) {
    array[0] = 3;
    number = 2;
}
```

Now if you start this, the output will be:

```
Array[0] = 3
number = 10
```

That might seem odd to you, but it's the difference between pass by reference and pass by value. arrays can always be modified while primitive datatypes (like ints) can not.

Last thing I want to add:
Are you sure it's generateCard, deckOfCard and printCard? It feels like it should either be generateCards, deckOfCards and printCards (notice the 's' ;)) or generateDeck, deckOfCards and printDeck. But maybe that's just me ^^ Anyway that has nothing to do with making it work, so I don't really care.